# Refused app with custom calendar in iOS7 App

Tags: ios, calendar, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to develop an app where I show a calendar and the user select one date. I know the DatePicker have a mode to show only Day/Month/Year but I need to show to de users what days are not disponible, this is the reason why I need to put a Calendar, where show the Day of the weak and I can specify the hollydays.

From now I use one but when I update to the App Store, apple refuse in 2 times. This is the message from itunesConnect in the Resolution Center:

> 10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good it may be rejected
>   10.6
>
> We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:
>
> - Did not integrate with iOS features.
> - Did not include iOS features. For example, it would be appropriate to use native iOS buttons and iOS features.
>
> These examples identify types of issues discovered in your app but may not represent all such issues. It would be appropriate to thoroughly evaluate your app to address these types of issues.

My question is what can I do for put a calendar controlling the days that are not available?

Answer (score 0):

As always, the info from Apple about why they rejected your app is not very specific.

Let's assume that the custom calendar is the problem that led the reviewer to rejection. That's an assumption that may not be valid: they may have rejected your app just because you use strange or difficult-to-read colors, that you don't use native alerts or whatever.
So, to the point: if your calendar is a specific one with restrictions that the native calendar doesn't support, you should not change your code but give a better explanation why you have a custom calendar, and why it should be included into the app.

You should explain that in the review notes:
[image]

AFAIK, they DO read those notes. Some reviewers have made specific statements about the Review Notes when "talking" about an app rejection.
One last thing I would recommend, if all the above steps do not work is removing the app version from iTunesConnect, then create a new version (with the same content) and upload the binary. You could end up with a different reviewer and get your app accepted. This last formula is only based on chance.

BTW, you should check your English (mine is not very good either, but disponible --> available, all sentences should have a Subject, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think I was wrong in my assumptions. I have sent a message from the Resolution Center and this is what they replied me:

> Thank you for your feedback. While we do not provide guidance or
>   direction for specific content or features of an app, or pre-approval
>   for proposed application submissions, we look for apps that are
>   specific to the iOS platform and take the fullest advantage of iOS in
>   delivering a robust user experience. Even though the application
>   allows users to add appointment dates to his or her iCal, it would be
>   appropriate to integrate additional business details natively in the
>   application while maximizing the iOS platform potential.

After these, I think the problem comes from a method where I save information inside Calendar:

```
-(void)saveInCalendar{

    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) { return; }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cita en NaturSais %@ %@", _strTitle, [NSString stringWithString:_strLocalizador]];
        event.startDate = onlyDate; //today
        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        event.notes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"El localizador de su reserva es: %@", [NSString stringWithString:_strLocalizador]];
        event.location = @"Carrer del Pont, 1 Baixos 43205 Reus (Tarragona)";
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
        NSLog(@"Se han guardado los datos en el calendario");
    }];
}
```